# MonoTouch.Dialog crash

Tags: c#, ios, crash, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I have a small test app which just cycles between 3 pages.
Here is AppDelegate:

```
    public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        _session = new Session();
        _session.NextScreen += (screenIndex) => 
        {
            window.RootViewController = _viewControllers[screenIndex];
        };

        _viewControllers.Add(new Screen0(_session));
        _viewControllers.Add(new Screen1(_session));
        _viewControllers.Add(new Screen2(_session));

        // create a new window instance based on the screen size
        window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

        // If you have defined a view, add it here:
        // window.AddSubview (navigationController.View);
        window.RootViewController = _viewControllers[0];

        // make the window visible
        window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();

        return true;
```

If I put a button on each screen I can navigate from page to page, i.e.,

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        UIButton button = new UIButton(new RectangleF(30, 200, 80, 34));
        button.SetTitle("Go to 1", UIControlState.Normal);
        button.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => 
        {
            _session.ExittingScreen = 0;
        };
        View.AddSubview(button);
    }
```

WHen I use MonoTouch.Dialog however, I get intermitten crashes. Here's my code:

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        var rootElement = new RootElement("Register")
        {
            new Section()
            {
                new EntryElement("First Name", "required", ""),
                new EntryElement("Last Name", "required", ""),
                new EntryElement("Email Address", "required", ""),
                new EntryElement("Password", "required", "")
            },
            new Section()
            {
                new StyledStringElement("Submit you information", () => { _session.ExittingScreen = 1; })
            }
        };
        var dialogViewController = new DialogViewController(rootElement);
        var navigationController = new UINavigationController(dialogViewController);

        View.Add (navigationController.View);
```

and the dump:

> at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>
>     at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],string,string) <0x000b7>
>     at MTD.Application.Main (string[]) <0x00017>
>     at (wrapper runtime-invoke) .runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>

Native stacktrace:

```
0   MTD                                 0x00090b7c mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 284
1   MTD                                 0x00005f28 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 248
2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x97da559b _sigtramp + 43
3   ???                                 0xffffffff 0x0 + 4294967295
4   UIKit                               0x02220952 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 201
5   Foundation                          0x0173786d __NSFireDelayedPerform + 389
6   CoreFoundation                      0x01195966 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 22
7   CoreFoundation                      0x01195407 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 551
8   CoreFoundation                      0x010f87c0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1888
9   CoreFoundation                      0x010f7db4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 212
10  CoreFoundation                      0x010f7ccb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
11  GraphicsServices                    0x04789879 GSEventRunModal + 207
12  GraphicsServices                    0x0478993e GSEventRun + 114
13  UIKit                               0x02190a9b UIApplicationMain + 1175
14  ???                                 0x09ff6774 0x0 + 167733108
15  ???                                 0x09ff5958 0x0 + 167729496
16  ???                                 0x09ff57f0 0x0 + 167729136
17  ???                                 0x09ff587f 0x0 + 167729279
18  MTD                                 0x0000a292 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 722
19  MTD                                 0x0016a17e mono_runtime_invoke + 126
20  MTD                                 0x0016e264 mono_runtime_exec_main + 420
21  MTD                                 0x00173685 mono_runtime_run_main + 725
22  MTD                                 0x00067495 mono_jit_exec + 149
23  MTD                                 0x002116c9 main + 2825
24  MTD                                 0x000032e5 start + 53
```

25  ???                                 0x00000005 0x0 + 5

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug? Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify, it crashes when I touch the "Submit" SyledStringElement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid patterns like:

```
var navigationController = new UINavigationController(dialogViewController);
View.Add (navigationController.View);
```

because `navigationController` won't be referenced (on the **managed** side) once the `View.Add` call is done and the garbage collector can dispose it (whenever it wants). However from the **native** side it will be expected to exist. Calls going back (from **native** to **managed**) to the disposed instance will crash your application.

The right pattern is to declare `navigationController` as a field (instead of a local variable) of your type and create/assign it in the method. This will keep a reference to `navigationController` alive as long as the parent instance exists (and ensure any callback won't go to a disposed object).

E.g.

```
private UINavigationController navigationController;
...
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    ...
    var dialogViewController = new DialogViewController(rootElement);
    navigationController = new UINavigationController(dialogViewController);

    View.Add (navigationController.View);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That seems to have stopped the intermittent crashes.

Comment: Great news :-) Lines, such as `3   ???                                 0xffffffff 0x0 + 4294967295`, usually point out to an instance that's does not exist anymore (even more when called from a native frame).