# iPhone Monotouch Application Crash at launch

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios

When open application (developed using Monotouch) in iPhone, Application is crash when it is launch

> Date/Time:       2012-02-17 21:57:44.970 +1100
>
> OS Version:      iPhoneOS 4.3.5 (8L1)
>
> Report Version:  104
>
> Exception Type:  00000020
>
> Exception Codes: 0x8badf00d
>
> Highlighted Thread:  0
>
> Application Specific Information: Tender failed to launch in time
>
> Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 2.120 (user 1.420, system 0.700),
>   11% CPU  Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 1.200, 6% CPU

This is crash report

I just create object for view and added to window

My Startup code is

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();
iTenderLoginView loginView;
loginView = new iTenderLoginView (window);
window.AddSubview (loginView.View);
return true;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: That obviously is a watchdog kill due to prolonged startup time. You will need to post your startup code for us to be able to help.

Comment: It is only take 2.2 seconds. I think ios allow up to 10 seconds

Comment: @Till Thank you for your reply. I just added my start up code.

Comment: The (symbolicated) crash report will explain exactly what the app was doing when it was killed - can you add that too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically doing a local variable for a view, like this:

```
iTenderLoginView loginView;
loginView = new iTenderLoginView (window);
window.AddSubview (loginView.View);
```

will cause a problem since `loginView` won't be referenced after the `AddSubview` call and the GC will be free to collect the instance. Promote the `loginView` local variable into a **field** of your `AppDelegate` and this should fix your crash.

See my answer for https://stackoverflow.com/a/9254218/220643