# In MonoTouch.Dialog what do I need to do to make datetime pickers have and "ok" and "cancel" option?

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

In MonoTouch.Dialog what do I need to do to make datetime pickers have and "ok" and "cancel" option?

In this example code when you click a DateTime element you navigate to the picker screen there is no way to select or cancel after you navigate to the date picker.

```
[Register ("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
{
    protected UIWindow window;
    protected UINavigationController navigationController;
    protected RootElement rootElement;
    protected DialogViewController dialogViewController;        

    public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
        var navigationController = new UINavigationController();
        window.AddSubview (navigationController.View);
        window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();

        rootElement = CreateJsonItems();
        dialogViewController = new DialogViewController (rootElement, true);
        navigationController.PushViewController (dialogViewController, true);

        return true;
    }

    protected RootElement CreateJsonItems()
    {
        var json = 
            @"{
                ""title"": ""Json Sample"",
                ""sections"": [{
                    ""header"": ""Dates and Times"",
                    ""elements"": [{
                        ""type"": ""datetime"",
                        ""caption"": ""Date and Time"",
                        ""value"": ""Sat, 01 Nov 2008 19:35:00 GMT""
                    }, {
                        ""type"": ""date"",
                        ""caption"": ""Date"",
                        ""value"": ""10/10""
                    }, {
                        ""type"": ""time"",
                        ""caption"": ""Time"",
                        ""value"": ""11:23""
                    }]
                }]
            }";

        using(var reader = new StringReader(json))
        {
            var jsonObject = JsonObject.Load(reader) as JsonObject;
            var jsonElement = JsonElement.FromJson(jsonObject);
            return jsonElement;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you [Poupou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/220643/poupou)! after applying your advice this is the code that fixed it.

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
    rootElement = CreateJsonItems();
    var dialogViewController = new DialogViewController(rootElement);
    navigationController = new UINavigationController(dialogViewController);
    window.Add (navigationController.View);
    window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When used like this in MonoTouch.Dialog the pickers are not modal. So it's the navigation UI that *will* let you go back to the previous view. OTOH that will be hidden by doing this:

```
   var navigationController = new UINavigationController();
   window.AddSubview (navigationController.View);
```

**note**: it's also a ([different](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9254218/220643)) problem since that won't keep a reference to `navigationController`.

You should try to replace the above (and move it after the creation of your `DialogViewController`) with:

```
   window.RootViewController = dialogViewController;
```

That should let the default navigation UI come back and allow you to go back from the date picker.